# Converting .OVA-formatted VM to Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-vmdk

I am struggling with importing an .OVA VM into my Hyper-V infrastructure. 
I managed to extract the .ova file using `tar` which yields three fiels - `.ovf` `.mf` and `.vmdk`. The `.mf`-contained SHA1 sums matched the `.vmdk` file. The .vmdk seems to be in the `stream-optimized` format in version 9 according to the data contained in the `ovf` and the `.vmdk` file's contents:

```
createType="streamOptimized"

# Extent description
RDONLY 104857600 SPARSE "generated-stream.vmdk"
```

I tried VirtualBox' `VBoxManage` to perform the conversion, but without success:

```
# VBoxManage clonehd --format VHD MyVM-disk1.vmdk MyVM.vhd
/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxManage: /usr/lib/vmware-vix-disklib/lib64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so)
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Failed to clone hard disk. Error message: Could not open the medium storage unit '/home/dj/MyVM-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: incorrect ordering of entries in descriptor in '/home/dj/MyVM-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER).
VBoxManage: error: VD: error VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER opening image file '/home/dj/MyVM-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_VD_VMDK_INVALID_HEADER)
```

My vSphere hosts would not accept the `.vmdk` for a valid disk too, so I tried converting it to `growable` using `vmware-vdiskmanager` from the 5.1.1 VDDK which is available from [the VMWare site](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/get-download?downloadGroup=VSP510-VDDK-51U1). Yet, this also did not work out as intended:

```
# vmware-vdiskmanager -r ./myVM-disk1.vmdk -t 0 ./myVM-growable.vmdk
Creating disk './myVM-growable.vmdk'
Failed to convert disk: The file specified is not a virtual disk (0xf00003ebf).
```

What's wrong here? How do I get it converted / imported properly?

Comment: Did you try qemu-img?

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha I did, but it seems my version (1.0) does not support the `vhd` output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a mistake using `VBoxManage` from the VirtualBox package. The call has altered the VMDK and apparently has rendered it invalid. I would not have expected VBoxManage to *write* to the source file, thus it took a while before I noticed that I am trying to work with a broken virtual disk.